# Extracting the files with the largest size in terminal

Tags: bash, shell, terminal

I have a folder with *100,000* images. This folder is made up of *1000* images each with *100* variations of each image. Each variation has different file size and a random suffix. For example:

```
image-of-a-cat-1a.jpg (50Kb)
image-of-a-cat-6b.jpg (100Kb)
image-of-a-cat-3f.jpg (75Kb)
image-of-a-cat-8d.jpg (25Kb)
and so on
```

I have a list of *500* of these file names that I want out of the total *100,000* but my list doesn't have the random suffixes or the '.jpg'. For example:

```
image-of-a-cat
image-of-a-dog
image-of-a-bird
and so on
```

Is it possible to:

1. Search for only the image variations for the 500 that I want. (we can delete the others or move the *500* to a new folder)
2. Find the variation for each file name with the largest file size and remove the suffix. (again we can delete the others or move the *500* to a new folder)

For example:

```
image-of-a-cat.jpg (100Kb)
image-of-a-dog.jpg (100Kb)
image-of-a-bird.jpg (100Kb)
and so on
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Must it be a shell script?

Comment: Bash has no built-in mechanism for determining file size. The `stat` command would be the way to get this info, but its options vary depending on your operating system, and you haven't mentioned your operating system. (Note: I'm not asking for your operating system, I'm mentioning a secondary reason why this question is incomplete.) Please make an attempt to solve this yourself. Don't just ask for hand-outs.

Comment: Why not start by creating a temporary file holding the names of all files that match the 500 sorted by size? (e.g. like `cd dir; ls -1rS | grep -f file500 > ../tmpS`) Then simply read each of the files in your `file500` again in a loop (e..g. `read -r name; do ... ;done <file500`) and in the loop `grep "$name" ../tmpS | tail -n 1`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly and if your system is POSIX compliant, following code will work:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir choicest
while read line; do
    mkdir $line
    mv ${line}-*.jpg $line

    cd $line
    ls -l | sort -k 4 -r | head -n 1 | awk '{org=$9; sub(/-[^-]*\./, ".", $9); print org " ../choicest/"$9}' | xargs mv
    cd ..
done < listofnames
```

where the file "listofnames" contains the 500 names.